# semi-translucent objects in libgdx

Tags: opengl, libgdx

How does one create an object that is semi-translucent to light. I would like to block point light source to create an effect similar to that one shown in the image. Note the smooth transition, because the light permeability of blocker was gradually decreasing. How can I achieve this in libgdx? There is no need for a blocker, if there is another way to do this I am open to it.

**Blocker present:**

[image]

**Blocker not present:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ended up using ambient light with black and white gradient texture applied to the material I wanted to mask.